# Java: Is my input.readObject() getting truncated on either write or read?

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

I'm building a system to exchange encoded messages, call it bank and client.  The first messages that I need to exchange are long Strings.  They appear to be truncated either in the write or read, but I'm not sure how to figure out where.

Read:

```
client = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(bankServer), 12345);
displayMessage("Connected to: " + client.getInetAddress().getHostName());
input = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
inputString = (String) input.readObject();
```

Write:

```
 output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
 output.flush(); // flush output buffer to send header information
 output.writeObject(msgClassOut + msgTypeOut.toString() + key);
 output.flush();
```

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I would wrap them in `BufferedOutputStream`.  What is it getting truncated at, lengthwise?

Comment: It's getting truncated around 12-13 characters.  It should be a couple of hundred characters, a diffie-hellman parameter set.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  The "key" data was initially being sent as byte[].  I changed it to String and it's all getting transferred, no truncation.